# Angular CLI generated library - can't import components from it's module

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-cli

So I've made a simple Angular library using CLI `ng g library <library-name>` and I'm trying to import a component from it's module. I'm importing components.module in my app module in the imports array, but I want to be able to import a components class from this module to another component, simply by writing:

```
import {MyComponent} from ...;
```

But I can't do that - my IDE is saying that this Module has no exported members with the name of my component, and when I open open it looks like this:

```
export declare class ComponentsModule {
}
```

and public_api.d.ts {

```
export * from './lib/components.service';
export * from './lib/components.component';
export * from './lib/components.module';
```

Also, here is the library-name.d.ts file:

```
/**
* Generated bundle index. Do not edit.
*/
export * from './public_api';
export { ApiErrorComponent as ɵa } from './lib/modals/api-error/api-error.component';
export { ConfirmationModalComponent as ɵb } from './lib/modals/confirmation- modal/confirmation-modal.component';
export { InfoModalComponent as ɵc } from './lib/modals/info-modal/info- modal.component';
```

My module source file before ng build:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {ComponentsComponent} from './components.component';
import {ApiErrorComponent} from './modals/api-error/api-error.component';
import {ConfirmationModalComponent} from './modals/confirmation-modal/confirmation-modal.component';
import {InfoModalComponent} from './modals/info-modal/info-modal.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  declarations: [
    ComponentsComponent,
    ApiErrorComponent,
    ConfirmationModalComponent,
    InfoModalComponent,
  ],
  exports: [
    ComponentsComponent,
    ApiErrorComponent,
    ConfirmationModalComponent,
    InfoModalComponent,
  ],
})
export class ComponentsModule {
}
```

Why doesn't it work  and why I can't import any of these components? It was auto generated from Angular CLI using ng build library-name. In the package I also have few directiories beside "lib" - ems2015, esm5, fesm5, fesm2015 and bundles, but I thought that I will be able to just import my module and use any component from it wherever I like - but it look like they are private or something and the documentation on generating and building libraries using CLI is not so good.

Will apppreciate all the help.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you find a solution by then. I came across the same problem and let me share my solution.

Modify your public_api.d.ts in your library to include all your custom components. So in your case, it should be like:

```js
export * from './lib/modals/api-error/api-error.component';
export * from './lib/modals/confirmation- modal/confirmation-modal.component';
export * from './lib/modals/info-modal/info- modal.component';
```

Then, run `ng build <library-name>` When library-name.d.ts looks like this, all your components are exported.

```js
export * from './public_api';
```

To import components in another module, do like this:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {ComponentsComponent} from './components.component';
import {ApiErrorComponent} from 'library-name';
import {ConfirmationModalComponent} from 'library-name';
import {InfoModalComponent} from 'library-name';
```

Comment: would it be possible to have one library but group it inside so then I can do: `import { SomeService } from '@myOrg/lib/services';` and `import { SomeEntity } from '@myOrg/lib/model'` ?

Comment: i did the same but it says cannot find module , how will the new module know the where abouts of the built module

Comment: I could not import the component after exporting it this way. As a workaround I import it with the full path after the name of the library. i.e. import { MyComponent } from "my-lib/path/to/component"

Answer (score 0):

I had followed this nice little guide to create a library to test adding it to my local npm registry (Verdaccio).
https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/06/16/angular-npm-how-to-publish-an-angular-component-to-npm

But when I tried to import the library's module in my consuming app it couldn't find it, even though I could see the folder was in my node_modules. The problem was when I published it after the ng build, I had missed the step to be in the library project's dist/my-library-name folder. Once I published a newer version from the correct location, I was able to import the module into my consuming app.